# How do you spec a digest auth in Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, authentication, rspec, sinatra, digest-authentication

I have a digest auth set up like the example from the sinatrarb website.

```
#config.ru
require './main'

app = Rack::Auth::Digest::MD5.new(Sinatra::Application) do |username|
  {'foo' => 'bar'}[username]
end
app.realm = 'Protected Area'
app.opaque = 'secretkey'

run app
```

I was wondering if anyone knows how or can point me to a guide rspecing this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Sinatra FAQ](http://www.sinatrarb.com/faq.html#test_http_auth) has an example using Test::Unit and Basic Auth. I've never used RSpec with Sinatra but it should be easy to translate the example from Test::Unit.

Even though the example use Basic Auth, Digest Auth can be tested the same way. The only difference is you need to use Rack::Test's [digest_authorize](http://rdoc.info/github/brynary/rack-test/master/Rack/Test/Session#digest_authorize-instance_method) method instead. For example, the last test in the FAQ would become this:

```
def test_with_proper_credentials
  digest_authorize 'admin', 'admin'
  get '/protected'
  assert_equal 200, last_response.status
  assert_equal "You're welcome", last_response.body
end
```

Comment: Oooh I didnt see that. Thanks a lot! Haha I thought it was going to be something more complicated.